# Naviagtion items are missing after installing the app

Tags: package, upload, installedpackage, navigatetocomponent

I created an app in salesforce and it has a Navigation item called 'Patients' which displays a list. This is the screeshot:
[image]

Now, i created a managed package for this app and uploaded as beta. After the upload, i got the Url. Using that url, I installed the app in another org. And, when i open the app, **there is no navigation item**. [image]

This is my first time creating a package and uploading it. So, i cant figure out what i did wrong. Can anybody please help?

EDIT:
When i created the package, the 'Patients' tab is getting added to the package. I have confirmed it. Also, when I go to 'Installed Packages', open the package and go to 'View Components' in the second org, the 'Patients' tab is present there.

Comment: is custom domain enabled at installed org?

Comment: i dont know. how can i do that?

Comment: Here is a guide how to enable it - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=environment_hub_get_started_my_domain.htm. Be sure that you understand consequences (so do not do it on your production org, but only on development)

Comment: thanks for the help. is that the reason why the tabs are not visible?

Comment: So did it work or not? Reason is that salesforce requires custom domain to be enable to make apps with lightning components to be working

Comment: it dint work. i checked by reloading the app page. Do i have to uninstall and install the app again?

Comment: I fixed it. I went to Profiles -> Edit System Administrator. In that, `Patients` tab was Hidden. I changed it to 'Default On'. After doing this, tab is visible. Is there any way it can be done automatically?